# Best Approaches to streamline production design for assets

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, sketch-app, automation, data-merge

I'm looking for some suggestions for how to do best manage a design pipeline that requires lots of assets that need to be created based off a few core templates.

For our marketing we have 2-3 core templates that require us to change some of the images/copy/elements in a variable way (E.g. if we are creating an asset for Chicago vs Los Angeles we'll use a different map, different asset and change the city name). Off a core template we might generate 50+ variations so its can be very labor intensive to do this manually in Photoshop.

We are a tech-savvy team so there are no limitations on programming etc. Our main goal is to be able to have a designer provide a template and then "automate it" in such a way as we can constantly plug in new values to generate new assets. Hopefully the marketer who wants the asset doesn't have to fool around with too many design tools.

Right now the only thing I have come up with is using Sketch Symbols. We could create a template as a Symbol and then use the overrides. It still requires opening Sketch and doing a bunch of stuff.

What other tools/processes work for producing assets at this scale? We are open to Adobe Suite or anything else.

UPDATE (someone said I was being to Vague so here is a very specific example):

We have an advertisement that needs to run in many DMAs. 
We have a core template that contains the following design elements:

**MY TEMPLATE**
Layer 1: City Name  + extra copy 
Layer 2: Image of a map outline (will vary per city)
Layer 3: Small App Icon Logo (will vary per city)
Layer 4: Call To action button (will vary as we experiment), (Background color code will also vary)
Background Color Layer: Doesn't Change

Ideally I would have a spreadsheet or database entry where I can input

**MY VARIABLES**
Variable A: Los Angeles
Variable B: Link to Los Angeles City Map Outline Image
Variable C: Link to App Icon Logo for Los Angeles
Variable D: Text I want to use in Call to action
Variable E: Background Color for Call to Action.

I want to have lots of rows **MY VARIABLES** be able to generate assets of **MY TEMPLATE**

My dream workflow would be :

1. Designer exports a template from Adobe product and
2. Developer integrates that into a web UI that has ties data entry form inputs to that template
3. Marketer can then just generate new assets from the Web UI by entering variables in a form.

Comment: You are being too vague for help. You shoudl probably not be using photoshop, something like illustrator, indesign, affinity designer should be much better

Comment: I would also suggest a page layout program like InDesign and using XML to import the assets.

Comment: This is also possible in Photoshop using data sets or scripting. Really depends on your assets and input files.

Comment: @joojaa just tried to clarify and be more specific. Which of the tools is best for the job in your opinion and what should I be googling about those tools to learn about how to best set this up?